# Bitmap that follows your finger instantly

Tags: java, android, position, motionevent, instant

I want a bitmap to follow my finger. But when I use MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE the bitmap lags behind. Is there a way the bitmap follows instantly (or almost instantly) your finger?

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) 
{   
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(me.getAction())
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(me.getX() > player.get_RectXPos() && me.getX() < player.get_RectXPos() + player.get_Width() && 
           me.getY() > player.get_RectYPos() && me.getY() < player.get_RectYPos() + player.get_Height())
        {
            isDown = true;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        isDown = false;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if(isDown == true)
        {
            player.set_xPos(me.getX());
            player.set_yPos(me.getY());
        }

        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think you asked for this part:

```
    void render(Canvas canvas)
{
    m_Src = new Rect(0, 0, m_RectWidth, m_RectHeight);
    m_Dst = new Rect(m_RectX, m_RectY, m_RectX + m_RectWidth, m_RectY + m_RectHeight);
    canvas.drawBitmap(m_Bitmap, m_Src, m_Dst, null);
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: can you also post the function of drawing the Bitmap?

Comment: I used canvas.drawBitmap(...) to render it.

Comment: Do you redraw the whole screen everytime ?

Comment: The onDraw code shouldn't be any secret here :) but gives us information what's wrong

Comment: Well I have to render the bitmap everytime, because it changes its position

Comment: How are you invoking a redraw? Are you calling `invalidate()` inside `onTouch()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void render(Canvas canvas)
{
m_Src = new Rect(0, 0, m_RectWidth, m_RectHeight);
m_Dst = new Rect(m_RectX, m_RectY, m_RectX + m_RectWidth, m_RectY + m_RectHeight);
canvas.drawBitmap(m_Bitmap, m_Src, m_Dst, null);
}
```

Here you allocate 2 `Rect` objects each time. You should initialize them only once and use `Rect.set` to change their values.

Also if your `Bitmap` size should not change, you could use `public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)` since this method doesn't do any scaling/translation to the `Bitmap` and should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You must do some unnecessary work on your `onTouch` method. Because it should not be laggy if you only change its position.

Edit:
You can save your `Rect` m_Src and m_Dst and just change their coordinates in your render.
That will save a lot of work for the system and the garbage collection.

Comment: This ain't really an answer, you could comment the question with OP

Comment: That's true.. i'm kinda new here didn't know sry

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the "onTouch" handler interrupts everytime the drawing...

Your "onDraw" routine should be located in its proper thread (maybe ASyncTask could do the job too). You'll have then to forward the x,y coordinates of your finger to the gui thread.

Type "Thread Gui Android" in google for a comprehensive example :)